# Solving $x - \dfrac{1}{ \lfloor x \rfloor } = \lfloor x \rfloor$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Determine the three smallest positive solutions to the equation $$x -
> \dfrac{1}{ \lfloor x \rfloor } = \lfloor x \rfloor$$

This is my attempt:
If $x$ is an integer, we have:

$$x^2-1=x^2,$$
which has no solutions. Therefore, $x$ cannot be an integer. We can therefore assume that $x=n+\delta$, where $n$ is an integer  and $0<\delta<1$. We thence obtain:

$$(n+\delta) - \dfrac{1}{ \lfloor n+\delta \rfloor } = \lfloor n+\delta \rfloor,$$
which gives
$$(n+\delta) - \dfrac{1}{ n} = n$$
$$\delta=\frac1n$$

Since $0<\delta<1$, $n_1=1,\ n_2=2\, n_3=3$. Hence, $$x=(1+\delta), \ x_2=(2+\delta), \ x_3=(3+\delta)$$

But can this be right? I have the feeling something is odd here. Do I have to specify $\delta$? That can be as small as we like...

Thanks

Comment: $1.2 - \frac{1}{\lfloor{1.2}\rfloor} = 0.2 \neq \lfloor{1.2}\rfloor$

Comment: When $n=1$ there is a problem… also for each $n$ there is a unique $\delta$ , which is equal to $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: $\delta$ depends on $n$.

Comment: Your conclusion $\delta=\frac1n$ is subject to your assumption $0<\delta<1$, and so there is no solution when $n=1$.  So the smallest positive solutions are $n+\frac1n$ with $n=2,3,4$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quicker way to find the solution would be notice that the original equation can be rewritten as

$$\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor} = \{x\}$$

where $\{\cdot\} = \cdot - \lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes the fractional part function. This means the solutions are of the form

$$x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}$$

or

$$x_n = \frac{n^2+1}{n}$$

for $n\geq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct.

Choose any integer $n\gt 1$, then $x=n+1/n$ will be a solution. Note that $\lfloor x\rfloor=n$.

So $x-\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}=n+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n}=\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

$x\in\Bbb R$ solves $x-\frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor}=\lfloor x\rfloor$ if and only if there is some $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $(x,n)$ solves $$\begin{cases}x-\frac1n=n\\ n\le x<n+1\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} n\ne 0\\ x=n+\frac1n\\ n\le n+\frac1n\\ n+1>n+\frac1n\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} n\ne 0\\ x=n+\frac1n\\ 0\le \frac1n\\ \frac{1-n}n<0\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}  x=n+\frac1n\\  n>1\end{cases}$$

Therefore $x$ solves the equation if and only if there is some integer $n>1$ such that $x=n+\frac1n$.

In general, given $F$ in two variables, you can convert an inequation $F(x,\lfloor x\rfloor)\le 0$ (or $=$, or $>$, or whatever) to the equivalent problem $$\exists n\in\Bbb Z, (n\le x<n+1\land F(x,n)\le 0)$$ and then use the high-school machinery if feasible.